# Maximum length of statement in C

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a maximum length for a statement defined in C?

compiler is gcc

Comment: I realize you asked for C; the C++ spec offers a guideline that a logical line should support at least 65535 characters.

Comment: Did you encounter a long statement that was rejected by gcc? It's probably a bug, then.

Comment: According to C11 standard, it's 4095 characters. But I hope that you never reach this limit (this is not readable at all).

Comment: @md5: there's a 4095 character limit on a logical line, but a statement is not limited to being on a single logical line.

Answer (score 11):

The standard specifies a minimum translation limit:

> [c11](/questions/tagged/c11)
>
> #### 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> 1 The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that
>   contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:
>
> [...]
>
> — 4095 characters in a logical source line

The standard recommends however that "*implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible*".

A logical source line is the result of backslash-newline splicing (5.1.1.2:1.2), so this doesn't directly cover the minimum limit for the number of characters in a statement.

However, because another translation limit requirement is:

> — 4095 characters in a string literal (after concatenation)

and as string literals may only occur in statements, it follows that the implementation must accept at least one 4095-character statement.

Ignoring literals, we also see:

> — 127 arguments in one function call

and as a function call must include at least 2 characters per argument, plus 4 for the invocation (`f(0,0,...);`) we arrive at a minimum line length limit of 260.

Comment: "string literals may only occur in statements" - that isn't true, for example `const char *foo = "hello, world";` is a declaration, not a statement. But it doesn't really matter, since the lower bound on statement length that you derived from it is nominal anyway.

Comment: Guessing a sequence of statements with [continuations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969394/how-to-split-long-lines-of-code-in-c) must also be 4096 bytes (or less) in toto, not each.

Answer (score 7):

The C standard lays down a variety of lower bounds on the complexity of the language that must be accepted by a compiler, but not a limit on the length of a statement per se.

> #### §5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that
>   contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:<sup>18)</sup>
>
> - 127 nesting levels of blocks
> - 63 nesting levels of conditional inclusion
> - 12 pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combinations) modifying an
>     arithmetic, structure, union, or void type in a declaration
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized declarators within a full declarator
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression
> - 63 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name (each
>     universal character name or extended source character is considered a single
>     character)
> - 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier (each universal character name
>     specifying a short identifier of 0000FFFF or less is considered 6 characters, each
>     universal character name specifying a short identifier of 00010000 or more is
>     considered 10 characters, and each extended source character is considered the same
>     number of characters as the corresponding universal character name, if any)<sup>19)</sup>
> - 4095 external identifiers in one translation unit
> - 511 identifiers with block scope declared in one block
> - 4095 macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one preprocessing translation unit
> - 127 parameters in one function definition
> - 127 arguments in one function call
> - 127 parameters in one macro definition
> - 127 arguments in one macro invocation
> - 4095 characters in a logical source line
> - 4095 characters in a string literal (after concatenation)
> - 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
> - 15 nesting levels for #included files
> - 1023 case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested switch
>     statements)
> - 1023 members in a single structure or union
> - 1023 enumeration constants in a single enumeration
> - 63 levels of nested structure or union definitions in a single struct-declaration-list
>
> <sup>18)</sup> Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.
>
> <sup>19)</sup> See ‘‘future language directions’’ (6.11.3).
>
> #### §6.11.3 External names
>
> Restriction of the significance of an external name to fewer than 255 characters
>   (considering each universal character name or extended source character as a single
>   character) is an obsolescent feature that is a concession to existing implementations.

As you can see, footnote 18 would discourage the imposition of such a restriction.

Having said all that, I'd hate to see a single statement that encroached on the limits.  It had better be machine-generated and not human written.

Comment: /me goes to write a program that reaches each of these limits.

Comment: @lynks I want to see the source code of that!  You've been at it for nearly 6 years by now!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby legend has it he's still going