# Is it legal to use \\ in // C++ comment? (LaTeX equation in C++ comment)

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

For documentation purpose I need to add some LaTeX equations in my C++ comments, by example:

```
//
// \begin{eqnarray*}
//   y_1 &=& x_1 \\
//   y_2 &=& x_2 
// \end{eqnarray*}
//
int main() {}
```

With clang++ (version 9.0.1-10) I can compile my code without problem:

```
clang++ -Wall prog.cpp
```

but with g++ (version 9.2.1)

```
g++ -Wall prog.cpp
```

I get this warning:

> ```
> prog.cpp:3:1: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
>     3 | //   y_1 &=& x_1 \\
>       | ^
> ```

**My question:** which compiler is right? Can I legally use `\\` inside C++ `//` comment?

Comment: My install of clang++ also gives out this warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such comments are legal, but they could have unexpected effects, hence the warning. The next line after the one with the backslash at the end is a continuation of the comment, regardless of the `//` at the beginning. So this

```
// \\
Hey dude!
int main () {}
```

is a valid C++ program. And no, the backslash before the last one does not serve as an escape.

If you want to avoid the warning, put a LaTeX comment in the end of the line:

```
// y_1 &=& x_1 \\ % look ma, no warning
```

Note that a simple space between the backslash and the newline doesn't necessarily fix the problem. GCC documentation says:

> If there is white space between a backslash and the end of a line, that is still a continued line. However, as this is usually the result of an editing mistake, and many compilers will not accept it as a continued line, GCC will warn you about it.

Comment: If I remember right the line continuation is the sequence backslash-newline. So, if I'm right a simple space after the backslash should fix it but a space is invisible and a LaTeX comment is even better. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff :"simple space after the backslash should fix" I thought so too. It doesn't. Clang even warns about this.

Comment: Concerning a simple space after backslash: This seems to work in MSVC but not in g++ nor in clang. So, the LaTeX comment (or any other non-space) is in fact the solution. [g++ and clang on CompilerExplorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W_Ny5-) [MSVC on regex](https://rextester.com/GXJ31939)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yepp. I just fiddled a bit. MSVC is the only one which seems to support it.

Answer (score 10):

Is it legal? Yes. Is it error prone? **Yes.** That's why you are getting a warning.

The C/C++ standard has one token above all (processed first): `\`

This token removes the line break. Consider the following code:

```
1.  // the below code is commented out \
2.  despite not having a comment at the beginning of the line
3.  
4.  // it's important to be careful because \\
5.  int not_compiled_code = 0;
6.  // the above code is not compiled.
```

Despite stackoverflow's syntax highlighting, lines 2 and 5 are not compiled.

In case you're wondering, the next tokens are `//` and `/*`.

```
// /* incomplete block comment
int compiled_code = 0;

/*
// this entire line isn't commented */ int compiled_code_2 = 0;
```

> which compiler is right?

Both, because warnings are irrelevant to the standard. They compiled successfully and that's all that matters - they both conformed properly to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

According to [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/comment)

> C++-style comments tell the compiler to ignore all content between // and a new line.

So your comment should be legal. Notice that g++ is only giving a warning, not an error.

[g++ is warning about the escaped newline](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

> Warn whenever a comment-start sequence ‘/*’ appears in a ‘/*’ comment, or whenever a backslash-newline appears in a ‘//’ comment. This warning is enabled by -Wall

Comment: Yes but `\\` is traditionally used to wrap long lines (https://stackoverflow.com/a/969402/2001017)... The problem is that I do not know what the standard exactly says...

Comment: It isn't illegal, g++ just thinks it is poor style

Answer (score 2):

A practical solution is to use `/*` multi-line comments. So code

```
/***
 \begin{eqnarray*}
   y_1 &=& x_1 \\
   y_2 &=& x_2 
 \end{eqnarray*}
***/
```

### You should be interested by [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) techniques, and by tools like [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html).

My recommendation is to try [Nuweb](http://nuweb.sourceforge.net/nuweb.pdf) (at least if you code on Linux), in particular for your public (and LaTeX documented) header files. You'll code a Nuweb source file (some `*.nw` file) which would generate LaTeX on one hand, and C code on another (e.g. some header file).

Be aware that using literate programming techniques takes a lot of time.  My personal but limited experience is that they are worth using more on public header files than on implementation details and entire [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Of course, you need to learn more about [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools (such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) and configure them explicitly for running your [`nuweb`](http://nuweb.sourceforge.net/) or `doxygen` executable appropriately.

Comment: I have to stick to C++ style '//' comment to be used by some tools for documentation generation with a [Org-Mode](https://orgmode.org/) backend

Comment: I had recognized you :). Yep I will send you an email. That's my own tool for extracting comment to generate some OrgMode doc. The problem with C comments is that they are slightly more complicated to parse than "monoline" comment like //, # or % etc... we generally see in other languages

Answer (score 1):

> which compiler is right?

Both. The warning is not about "legal usage of `\`" the warning is about multiline comment.

In C a `\` character on the end of the line means to ignore the newline. So the two lines:

```
// blabla\
abcabc
```

and:

```
// blabalabcbc
```

Are exactly equivalent. The double backslash `\\` is just a backslash `\` that is escaped by `\`, so it is first substituted by a backslash, then preprocessor detects backslashes followed by a newline and deletes newlines. That's why it's dangerous.

```
int a = 1;
// increase a \\
a++;
printf("%d\n", a); // will print `1`
```

Comment: \\ is not an escaped \ because it is not a string.